# Do I need to perform variable selection before running a ridge regression?

Tags: r, regression

I am currently constructing a model that uses last year's departmental information to predict employee churn for the current year.  I have 55 features and 318 departments in my data set.  A good portion of my independent variables are correlated, and because of this, I believe that performing a ridge regression on my data will lead to optimal predictions when I bring the model into production.  I have studied ridge regression and understand that the lambda coefficient computed for a given predictor can minimize the effect that predictor has on the model to next to nothing.  Does this mean that performing a ridge regression means I don't have to bother with variable selection? If I do need to perform a variable selection technique, would implementing a stepwise regression and then using those selected variables in my ridge regression be a valid approach at variable selection?